# Running agent with apache flume

Tags: flume-ng

I'm trying to download log data from twitter using my twitter apps using `flume 1.6v`.

But i'm facing this error constantly:

```
error>>/usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393/flume/bin/flume-ng.distro: line 247: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java/: Not a directory
/usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393/flume/bin/flume-ng.distro: line 247: exec: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java/: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

What do you think is the problem here? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if JAVA_HOME is set up correctly